# Sorting elements using jquery (trouble with numerical comparables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm using this [very handy plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) to sort elements. But comparing elements on a numerical value is producing an incorrect result: 99, 98, 9, 83, 8, 78, etc..

Would this be a problem of the plugin or the way I implemented it?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){
    var sort = [].sort;
    return function(comparator, getSortable) {
        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};
        var placements = this.map(function(){

            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );

            return function() {

                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);
            };

        });
        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.item').sortElements(function(a,b){
        return $(a).html() < $(b).html() ? 1 : -1;
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<% for i = 0 to 100 %>
<div class="item"><%=i*Rnd%></div>
<% next %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do a sort based on the numeric values of strings, then convert the strings to numbers with the [`parseInt` <sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method

```
$('.item').sortElements(function(a,b){
        return parseInt($(a).html(),10) < parseInt($(b).html(),10) ? 1 : -1;
    });
```

(*or [`parseFloat` <sup>MDN docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for floating point numbers, as Gaurav mentioned in the comments..*)

Comment: @GauravShah, yes to support decimal `parseFloat` should be used.. I went with the example values which are all integer..

Comment: It was just a suggestion to the questioner :)

Comment: I thought I was going nuts. Why wont it sort my decimal prices?I get these nonsensical results!?! Because its sorting by ASCII.. JavaScript...  - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings. In Javascript `"88" < "9"`, but (obviously) `88 > 9`, or (`+"88" > +"9"`). You should convert your strings to numbers in your compare function:

```
return +$(a).html() < +$(b).html() ? 1 : -1;
```